# page breaks do not work within section tags

Tags: html, css

I am making a project with django, html,css, and javascript and I am building a page with sections and scroll snapping. I am struggling to go down a line after my  tag but before my  tag within a section. when I tried using break tags nothing happens, even when I use multiple. My best guess is that the fact that I am trying to do it within a section tag

[image]

```
<body>
        <div class = "nav">
            <a href="#1">Home</a>
            <a href="#2">Education</a>
            <a href="#3">Projects</a>
            <a href="#4">Skills</a>
            <a href="#5">Experience</a>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll_container">
        <section id = "1" class = "home_section">
            <h1>Tyler Olson</h1>
            <img class="animate__animated animate__bounce" src="/static/down_arrow.png" alt="bouncing dodwn arrow" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        </section>
        ...
      </div>
      </body>
```

My goal is to have the arrow repeatedly bouncing at the bottom center of the section but I am completely unable to move it down rn, I even tried modifying some css values to move the img tag but none of them did anything

Answer (score 0):

May be this Answer Helpful For Your Try This

```
<style>
    
    .animate__bounce {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        animation: bounce 0.5s;
        animation-direction: alternate;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.5, 0.05, 1, .5);
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
      
    @keyframes bounce {
        from {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
        to {
            transform: translate3d(0, 200px, 0);
        }
    }
    /* Prefix Support */
      
    animate__bounce {
        -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
        -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(
        .5, 0.05, 1, .5);
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
      
    @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 200px, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 200px, 0);
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: this seems like a way to animate an infinitely bouncing arrow but it does not seem to move the arrow down to the bottom of the page which is my main goal rn if you look at my image the arrow appears on the same line as the title and I would like to move it to the very bottom center of the section. but <br> does not work, and neither do top, bottom etc in css. Thank you for the animation implementation though